# All SimpleMembership tables not creating

Tags: asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

I am implementing SimpleMembership with Entity Framework in my project. I have studied that 4 tables are created (Membership,OAuthMembership,Roles and UsersInRoles). 
But when I implement Simplemembership, it is creating only 2 tables: Membership and OAuthMembership.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you register a new user? It's only when you do this that the tables will be created?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, yes I registered a new user. It doesn't create 2 tables mentioned in the question.

Comment: You will have to provide more information and code on how you implemented SimpleMembership with Entity Framework to get a useful answer.